# How to apply formula based on the lag of each group

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a projection of a variable in several groups based on the first value of each one. I want to create a column which values depend on the lag of another column. This is a reproducible example:

```
#Create dataframe
year <- c(2016:2020, 2016:2020, 2016:2020)
group <- as.character(c(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), c(5,5,5))))
gdp <- as.numeric(c(100,0,0,0,0,100,0,0,0,0,100,0,0,0,0))
cagr <- c(rep(c(0.3, 0.6, 0.9), c(5,5,5)))

df <- data.frame(year, group, gdp, cagr)


df <- df %>%
group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(forecast_gdp = first(gdp), #Setting the starting point to be 100
         forecast_gdp = forecast_gdp[-1]*(1+cagr))
```

This is not working as every column has the values of the first row of each group*(1+cagr), but I want is the lag of each group*(1+cagr). Does anybody knows how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your example is missing the desired output. I'm not sure what the desired result is exactly. `dplyr` does have a `lag()` function that you might want to use. Be careful when resuing column names. First you create `forecast_gdp = first(gdp)` so it only has one value. Then you do `forecast_gdp[-1]` so if you remove the only value it has it now has nothing. Plus `mutate()` needs to return the same number of values for each column. You don't want to have `forecast_gdp` be length one less than `cagr`

Comment: Do you want something like `mutate(forecast_gdp = first(gdp) * cumprod(1+cagr)`?

Comment: Yes Martin! That's exactly what I want thank you! I tried your code and the only thing to correct is that I need the first value to be the starting point (100 for each group)